# How do y1 and y2 take on two different values here? Can someone please explain the order of assignments?

Tags: verilog, race-condition

The following code snippet is an example from a [SNUG 2000 paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) that explains race conditions. The explanation for the race condition is given below, but I do not understand it. How is y1 and y2 = 1 if the first always block executes first? Or 0 if the second block executes first? Can someone please explain the order of execution each statement?

Moreover, when the explanation says "after a reset", does it mean after a reset signal is asserted or de-asserted?

Code:

```
module fbosc1 (y1, y2, clk, rst);
 output y1, y2;
 input clk, rst;
 reg y1, y2;

 always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
 if (rst) y1 = 0; // reset
 else y1 = y2;

 always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
 if (rst) y2 = 1; // preset
 else y2 = y1;
endmodule
```

Explanation:

According to the IEEE Verilog Standard, the two always blocks can be scheduled in any order.
If the first always block executes first after a reset, both y1 and y2 will take on the value of 1. If the second always block executes first after a reset, both y1 and y2 will take on the value 0. This clearly represents a Verilog race condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is intended to show two registers swapping their values on a clock edge. "After reset" means *after* reset is de-asserted, but *before* the next posedge clock edge. In that period of time, y1 is 0 and y2 is 1.

So when the posedge `clk`, occurs, either the y1 = y2; assignment happens first, or the y2 = y1; happens first. Either way, the "other" value gets lost.

By changing the assignments to NBA `<=` both assignments use the previous values of `y1` and `y2`, so the order of assignments no longer matters.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your answer. Please tell me if I understood it right. If the first always block executes first, after reset, y1 = 0 and y2 = 1. Once the next posedge arrives, y1 will take the value of y2 so y1 and y2 = 1. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct-amundo.

Comment: Hi Dave, just saw your edit regarding NBA. If I use NBA, during the time after reset, what values would y1 and y2 take? In this case, isn't the previous value = 0 and 1 respectively? By previous, I assume you mean value in the previous timestep or previous posedge?